# Mobile safari like to skip timeout functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, safari

[image]

What I am doing is to activate the function 'keep checking()' and output a console once user touch swipe the iPad and delay for 100ms, but the output is below

[image]

I swiped 3 times slowly 1 by 1, there is only one attempt success, I wonder what causing this, it skipped the timer completly, no matter how long I wait it won't appears.
I tested on Desktop firefox/safari/chrome, they all works without problems, they never skip the timer even once.